# Can I edit the same Pages document on both my iPad and my Mac?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, pages, dropbox

I'm interested in editing a *single* Pages document on both a Mac and an iPad.

I understand the concept of "downloading" a document from iCloud (or from anywhere).

But that isn't what I want, because that would create a **copy** of the document, resulting in multiple versions.

So "sharing," "exporting," "copying," "downloading," etc. is what I'm trying to avoid.

I'm after something like when you have a file in Dropbox and you edit it on your work computer and then later go home and edit the same file there.

I'm guessing if it's at all possible it's going to involve iCloud, but if it can be done with Dropbox that would be preferable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, downloading it from iCloud won't create a copy. All of your changes will be synced back to iCloud from both devices, and conflicts will be dealt with appropriately (a dialog to you).

As long as both the Mac and the iPad are connected to the same iCloud account, you will be presented with a list of your documents whenever you start Pages on either your Mac or your iPad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have both devices configured to use the same iCloud account. How do I access my documents that are in iCloud? When I launch Pages on my Mac there's no list of documents, nor when I choose File > Open -- just the usual filesystem navigation dialog.

Comment: Do you have documents & data enabled in iCloud settings for both devices?

Comment: Yes, I have that enabled.

Comment: @Agvorth Does it work on your iPad?

Comment: I uploaded a Pages doc into my iCloud "iWork" area using the Web interface, thus creating a redundant copy. Now it appears in the Web interface and in Pages on my iPad. In OS X, when I double click it in a Web browser, iCloud offers to allow me to "download" it and offers "Pages '09" as the target location (which makes no sense -- how can a program be a filesystem location?) I accepted that and the document appeared as a third copy on my desktop. Pages desktop app not offering iCloud files. By any chance could there possibly be some way to do this that doesn't involve iCloud?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Undo. Don't know if it will work on my machine, but I appreciate the advice.